# Intellisense: type property index access vs dotted difference in suggested properties

Tags: typescript

I have an enum with some properties. For some of them, I want to assign them a payload. This payload will be what will be suggested by the autocompletion when the first parameter is the specified key.

```js
enum CorePlayerEvent {
    CLICK = "click",
    PLAY = "play",
    CANPLAY = "canplay",
    PLAYING = "playing",
    PAUSE = "pause",
    ERROR = "error",
    ENDED = "ended",
    LOADSTART = "loadStart",
    RATECHANGE = "ratechange",
    WAITING = "waiting",
    SEEKING = "seeking",
    SEEKED = "seeked",
    EMSG = "emsg",
    TIMEUPDATE = "timeupdate",
    VOLUMECHANGE = "volumechange",
    DURATIONCHANGE = "durationchange",
    ADDTRACK = "addtrack",
    PLAYBACK_BEGIN_HALTED = "playbackBeginHalted",
    START_TIME_AVAILABLE = "startTimeAvailable",
    CONTENT_STATE_CHANGED = "contentStateChanged",
    AUDIO_PLAY_RIGHT_ACQUIRED = "audioPlayRightAcquired",
    STATS_UPDATE = "statsUpdate"
}


interface CorePlayerMappedEvents {
    [CorePlayerEvent.DURATIONCHANGE]: number;
    [CorePlayerEvent.VOLUMECHANGE]: {
        volume: number;
        muted: boolean
    };
    [CorePlayerEvent.TIMEUPDATE]: number;
    [CorePlayerEvent.ERROR]: CorePlayerError;
    [CorePlayerEvent.RATECHANGE]: number;
    [CorePlayerEvent.CONTENT_STATE_CHANGED]: ContentState;
    [CorePlayerEvent.START_TIME_AVAILABLE]: number;
    [CorePlayerEvent.PLAYBACK_BEGIN_HALTED]: void;
    [CorePlayerEvent.AUDIO_PLAY_RIGHT_ACQUIRED]: boolean;
    [CorePlayerEvent.SEEKING]: number;
    [CorePlayerEvent.SEEKED]: number;
}
```

All the other events will have a default payload of `Event` (as they might be native events or cannot be remapped).

Then, I want to create an object that includes both. I make use of the mapped types to accomplish so.

```js
type CorePlayerUnmappedEvents = Record<Exclude<CorePlayerEvent, keyof CorePlayerMappedEvents>, Event>;

export type CorePlayerEventsMap = CorePlayerMappedEvents & CorePlayerUnmappedEvents;

export type CorePlayerObservableEvents = {
    [K in keyof CorePlayerEventsMap]: Observable<CorePlayerEventsMap[K]>;
};
```

Then I went to create an object that is going to honor the `CorePlayerObservableEvents`:

```js
const eventsObservables: CorePlayerObservableEvents = {
    [CorePlayerEvent.EMSG]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.CLICK]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.PLAY]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.CANPLAY]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.PLAYING]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.PAUSE]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.ERROR]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.ENDED]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.LOADSTART]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.RATECHANGE]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.WAITING]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.SEEKING]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.SEEKED]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.TIMEUPDATE]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.VOLUMECHANGE]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.DURATIONCHANGE]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.ADDTRACK]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.PLAYBACK_BEGIN_HALTED]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.START_TIME_AVAILABLE]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.CONTENT_STATE_CHANGED]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.STATS_UPDATE]: ...,
    [CorePlayerEvent.AUDIO_PLAY_RIGHT_ACQUIRED]: ...,
};
```

Now, if I open the autocomplete menu in VSCode on `eventsObservables`, I get two different behaviors based on dotted access and indexed access. Also, using properties out of autocompletion that are not suggested but correct, Typescript does not report me any error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The only difference between the two "kind" of properties is the suggested type on the right of the menu:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any pointer about this?

Comment: Apparently this is a Typescript bug. I opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56096